# Python subprocess.call() (to plot trees of Random Forest) isn't creating the output file

Tags: python, subprocess

I'm trying to run this python code (using anaconda):

```
RESULTS_PATH = 'C:\\...\\results\\'

from sklearn.tree import export_graphviz
# Export as dot file
export_graphviz(estimator, 
            out_file=RESULTS_PATH+'tree.dot', 
            feature_names = features,
            class_names = target_names,
            rounded = True, proportion = False, 
            precision = 2, filled = True)
```

The dot file is created at results location, but when trying to run:

```
# Convert to png
from subprocess import call
call(['dot', '-Tpng', RESULTS_PATH+'tree.dot', '-o', RESULTS_PATH+'tree.png', '-Gdpi=600']) #, shell=True)
```

I'm getting:

> FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

If I enable the `shell=True` option, getting "1" as return code (not success), and the png file isn't created!

What can be the issue?

## Update

I didn't figure out what was the issue, but mostly it was running this command under windows `$ dot -Tpng tree.dot -o tree.png`:

instead I used another code that do the same:

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows = 1,ncols = 1,figsize = (4,4), dpi=800)
tree.plot_tree(model_WD.estimators_[0],
           feature_names = features, 
           class_names=target_names,
           filled = True);
fig.savefig(RESULTS_PATH+'rf_individualtree.png')
```

Hope it wil help someone

Comment: "File not found" when attempting to write a new file usually means that the directory where you are trying to create a new file doesn't exist.

Comment: but the directory is there, and I can see the tree.dot file! the file and dir exists! os.path.isfile(RESULTS_PATH+'tree.dot') is returning true

Comment: Your call starts a subprocess. That subprocess doesn't necessarily have the working directory you think it has. If `dot.exe` isn't on the `PATH` , Windows will only find it if it is in what it thinks is the current working directory.